# Angular 4 *ngIf condition not working in IE but is working in Chrome

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a component and within the html code i have a div like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="isVtoError && !isVtoSkipped" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <strong>An Error Occured!</strong>
</div>
```

In the component ts file i have these fields declared at the top of the file like this:

```
 public isVtoSkipped = false;
 public isVtoError = false;
```

Within the init function i displayed the values to the console and they are both false like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.isVtoError);
  console.log(this.isVtoSkipped);
}
```

When I open the page using Google Chrome the div is hidden like it is supposed to but when I open the page in Internet Explore the div is showing.

I have read up on the polyfills.ts file and I have went through and installed the appropriate pages for IE and uncommented out some of the code.

Does anyone know why this div is showing in IE on the page load when it shouldn't be?

Comment: Which version of IE, you are using?

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr I have IE 11.0.9600.18816

Comment: caché problem ?

Comment: I second that, it looks like cache problem. You can clear the cache and cookies. Try then, it should work.

Answer (score -3):

Make  a `isVtoError` and `isVtoSkipped` as boolean, like this:

```
isVtoError :boolean = false;
isVtoSkipped :boolean = false;
```

Comment: TypeScript can infer the type of these variables from the assignment of the `false` value already.

Comment: No, you don't need to explicitly declare a value instantiated with true/fals as boolean